# Embed forms in Symfony

Tags: symfony1, sfdoctrineguard

I've added a profile class to sfDoctrineGuard, and in the admin I'm trying to edit the profile part while editing the user, using embed forms as explained here:

http://www.symfony-project.org/blog/2008/11/12/call-the-expert-customizing-sfdoctrineguardplugin
[image]

Editing users works, but when I add

> "User": [username, password,
>   password_again, **Profile**]

All I get is an error message :

> Widget "Profile" does not exist.

Any help would be appreciated. Is the blog post out of date ?

Comment: $this->embedRelation('Profile') does nothing, as soon as I add 'profile' to generator.yml, sf tells me that it doesn't know the widget 'profile'

Comment: I had lots of other problems, but one of them was that sf makes a difference between "profile" and "Profile" :D

Comment: So to answer my own question, the blogpost is not out of date, the method explained still works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a nice neat way to do this now.... Are you using 1.3 or 1.4?

In UserForm:

```
public function configure()
{
    $this->embedRelation('Profile');
}
```

Assuming that your schema is set up correctly, this will embed the form.

Comment: I've added the line to configure() of /lib/form/doctrine/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin but it doesn't appear to change anything to the form. No error messages either.

Comment: Thanks to whoever downvoted me. Next time a reason would be nice... @Manu - You are embedding the Profile form into your User form, so you should add this line to your UserForm class. I suspect that you might have an issue with your schema if this does not work. Have a look and make sure everything is in order.

Comment: I may have something wrong in my schema, but in the fixtures I can edit the "profile" part as I edit the "sfUserGuard" part.

Comment: $this->embedRelation('Profile'); does nothing, sf keeps telling me that it doesn't know the widget 'profile'